# How to open a .zip file which is embedded in .xlsx file?

Tags: macos, ms-office

I have a .zip file which has been embedded in a .xlsx file (excel ). But everytime I double click on the file it keeps giving this message:

Cannot start source application for this object. There may not be enough space in memory.

How can I open the .zip file? I have downloaded the unarchiver and also OpenXMLConvertor.But I dont know how to use them to extract the file.

I have Microsoft Excel 2011 (Version 14.0.0) and MAC OS X mountain lion, 64 bit , macbook air (2013). Kindly help

Answer (score 3):

The thing is - all Microsoft Office documents are ZIP files containing XML files. I would try this:

- copy the XLSX to another location
- Rename the copy by addin ".zip" to it (ignore the warnings)
- unzip the copy with your favourite tool (Unarchiver or terminal "unzip ")
- look through the folder structure and find your zip file.

Comment: Hi I did as you said. Within the folder structure I got an embeddings folder , opened that and unzipped the file. But now I have a compObj and native file. What should I do now?How do I make it readable?? :(

Comment: I have Office 365 mac 2011 edition and I didn't find any possibility to add a ZIP file as an embedded object to replay your problem. :-(

Sorry for that. So my help is a deadend. :-(

Comment: I had similar issue and I was able to fix it with you answer. On my mac - I changed the extension of the excel document with .cpgz, then unzipped it and all my pdf were in the embeddings folder. (and to open them I had to change the extension as well to pdf)

Answer (score 2):

I followed the answer from VISHAL DAGA above, with some minor variations.

1. Change the .xlsx to .zip
2. In terminal, run `unzip {{file}}`
3. In the resulting folder, change your directory to xl/embeddings
4. In that folder, there should be .bin files. Run `unzip {{ file }}.bin`
5. Profit! The file should now be accessible in its proper, unzipped form.